# Как получить PID процесса при запуске приложения?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Я запускаю свое приложение таким образом:

`python app.py`

Есть ли способ при запуске сделать так, чтобы `PID` процесса записался в нужный файл.

Можно ли сделать что-то типа такого: `python --pid pidfile app.py` ?

Comment: если нужно в рамках действующего скрипта то можно os.getpid(), в документации посмотреть можно https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python app.py& echo $! > pidfile
```

Процесс можно сразу вытащить из бэкграунда, если это необходимо:

```
python app.py& echo $! > pidfile; fg
```